# Python multithreading with openCV

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, numpy, opencv

I'm trying to run an object detection class in a separate thread and for some reason I cant grab the numpy array of data values back from the class object.. not sure why.  Code below.

**Main method**

```
detect = detector.Detection()

detect.start()

while(True): 

# get an updated image of the game
screenshot = wincap.get_screenshot()

detect.update(screenshot) 

detection_image = Vision.draw_rectangles(screenshot, detect.rectangles)
```

** Vision.draw_rectangles is a method that just uses OpenCV to find the objects given.. (it works, it was working before I tried to start multithreading the processes, and it still prints the correct output, I just cant pull the output from the thread. **

**Detector Method**

```
class Detection(object):


#threading props
stopped = True
lock = None
rectangles = []
 
#props
screenshot = None
 
def __init__(self):
    #create the thread lock object
    self.lock = Lock()
    
def update(self, screenshot):
    self.lock.acquire()
    self.screenshot = screenshot
    self.lock.release()

def start(self):
    self.stopped = False
    t = Thread(target=self.run)
    print("Started")
    t.start()
     
def stop(self):
    print("Stopped")
    self.stopped = True
      
def run(self):
    
    vision_mineral = Vision('C:/Users/Jordan/Desktop/Wakfu_Bot/Mining_bot/Resources/Copper.JPG')
    #initialize mine icon
    vision_mine_icon = Vision('C:/Users/Jordan/Desktop/Wakfu_Bot/Mining_bot/Resources/mineIcon.JPG')
    #global to define thread actions
    vision_loading_icon = Vision('C:/Users/Jordan/Desktop/Wakfu_Bot/Mining_bot/Resources/LoadingBar.JPG')
    
    while not self.stopped:
        if not self.screenshot is None:
            
            print("updating image")
            #object detection
            rectangles = vision_mineral.find(self.screenshot, 0.54)
            #define mining icon
            mine_icon = vision_mine_icon.find(self.screenshot, 0.6)
            #define loading icon
            loading_icon = vision_loading_icon.find(self.screenshot, 0.6)

            
            rectangles = np.concatenate((rectangles, mine_icon, loading_icon))
            
            
            self.lock.acquire()
            self.rectangles = rectangles
            self.lock.release()
```

Why isnt detect.rectangles returning the numpy array to the other class?  I've tried creating a "getRectangles" method, that doesn't work.  It prints the expected array INSIDE the thread but when I try and print detect. rectangles in the main function it returns an empty array.. How can I get the main function to grab the data from my detection class.

// For those who asked for it
**Vision Method**

class Vision:

```
#Constant
TRACKBAR_WINDOW = "Trackbars"

#props
img_tofind = None
img_tofind_w = None
img_tofind_h = None
method = None


def __init__(self, img_tofind_path, method=cv.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED):
    #load the image
    self.img_tofind = cv.imread(img_tofind_path)
    
    #Dimensions of the image
    self.img_tofind_w = self.img_tofind.shape[1]
    self.img_tofind_h = self.img_tofind.shape[0]
    
    
    # There are 6 methods to choose from:
    # TM_CCOEFF, TM_CCOEFF_NORMED, TM_CCORR, TM_CCORR_NORMED, TM_SQDIFF, TM_SQDIFF_NORMED
    method = cv.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED
    self.method = method
    
def find(self, screen_img, threshold=0.5, max_results=10):
    # run the OpenCV algorithm
    result = cv.matchTemplate(screen_img, self.img_tofind, self.method)

    # Get the all the positions from the match result that exceed our threshold
    locations = np.where(result >= threshold)
    locations = list(zip(*locations[::-1]))
    #print(locations)

    # if we found no results, return now. this reshape of the empty array allows us to 
    # concatenate together results without causing an error
    if not locations:
        return np.array([], dtype=np.int32).reshape(0, 4)

    # You'll notice a lot of overlapping rectangles get drawn. We can eliminate those redundant
    # locations by using groupRectangles().
    # First we need to create the list of [x, y, w, h] rectangles
    rectangles = []
    for loc in locations:
        rect = [int(loc[0]), int(loc[1]), self.img_tofind_w, self.img_tofind_h]
        # Add every box to the list twice in order to retain single (non-overlapping) boxes
        rectangles.append(rect)
        rectangles.append(rect)
    # Apply group rectangles.
    # The groupThreshold parameter should usually be 1. If you put it at 0 then no grouping is
    # done. If you put it at 2 then an object needs at least 3 overlapping rectangles to appear
    # in the result. I've set eps to 0.5, which is:
    # "Relative difference between sides of the rectangles to merge them into a group."
    rectangles, weights = cv.groupRectangles(rectangles, groupThreshold=1, eps=0.5)
    #print(rectangles)
    
    return rectangles

# given a list of [x, y, w, h] rectangles returned by find(), convert those into a list of
# [x, y] positions in the center of those rectangles where we can click on those found items
def get_click_points(self, rectangles):
    points = []

    # Loop over all the rectangles
    for (x, y, w, h) in rectangles:
        # Determine the center position
        center_x = x + int(w/2)
        center_y = y + int(h/2)
        # Save the points
        points.append((center_x, center_y))

    return points

# given a list of [x, y, w, h] rectangles and a canvas image to draw on, return an image with
# all of those rectangles drawn
def draw_rectangles(self, screen_img, rectangles):
    # these colors are actually BGR
    line_color = (0, 255, 0)
    line_type = cv.LINE_4

    for (x, y, w, h) in rectangles:
        # determine the box positions
        top_left = (x, y)
        bottom_right = (x + w, y + h)
        # draw the box
        cv.rectangle(screen_img, top_left, bottom_right, line_color, lineType=line_type)

    return screen_img

# given a list of [x, y] positions and a canvas image to draw on, return an image with all
# of those click points drawn on as crosshairs
def draw_crosshairs(self, screen_img, points):
    # these colors are actually BGR
    marker_color = (255, 0, 255)
    marker_type = cv.MARKER_CROSS

    for (center_x, center_y) in points:
        # draw the center point
        cv.drawMarker(screen_img, (center_x, center_y), marker_color, marker_type)

    return screen_img
```

Comment: we cannot see the Vision class, essential to understand your code

Comment: " Vision.draw_rectangles is a method that just uses OpenCV to find the objects given" -- if that is a cascade classifier -- those are not thread safe, neither are dnn's

Comment: It is not a cascade classifier.. it is properly getting the data within the detect class, I want to port the data from the detect class to the main function.  If you need to see the vision class I can post it.

Comment: please review [mre]. this is a lot of code. nobody will deal with that. your problem is likely solved by telling you to get a tutorial on multithreading. at this level of "problem", you won't get much engagement.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I had a minimal amount of code but was asked by commenters to provide more..

Comment: not "more". they asked for "complete", meaning reproducible, which is one of the characteristics of a [mre]. the other one is **minimal**, meaning you need to rip out everything that isn't required to *reproduce* the problem. don't just post partial code, nor your entire project.